# How do I execute system calls within a Wind River DKM?

Tags: vxworks

I am trying to make a DKM (Downloadable Kernel Module),`"my_dkm.o"`, that I can load into a custom VxWorks kernel in run-time. I was able to make a simple one (it prints "hello world") but I want my DKM to invoke system calls that already exist within the kernel that is running.

From the shell, I can do `-> syscallShow <my_group_#>,1` to give a list of the system calls I want to run. I can also invoke these system calls from the shell, but I don't know how to refer to them when developing my DKM.

Also, the Wind River Workbench help documentation only discusses invoking system calls from RTPs, which doesn't help because I am executing within kernel-space.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In Short:  You Don't

System call are exclusively to be used by RTPs to make a call to a function that resides in the kernel.  The system call itself does a bit of housekeeping and then invokes the underlying kernel routine.

In the context of a DKM, since you are already in the kernel space, you simply need to invoke the same underlying kernel function as the system call.